# Error ld: definiciones multiples de `obj ';

Tags: c++, c

He intentado compilar un programa que he estado escribiendo cuando me he encontrado con el error de ld: 'definiciones múltiples de `obj ';'.
He hecho de todo por intentar solucionarlo pero no lo he logrado.
He escrito esta parte del código para que se pueda entender.

A.h:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

int arr[10];
#endif
```

A.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

He intentado meter arr en una estructura llamada 's' creada en A.h, y crear un objeto de tipo 's' en A.h, pero pasa lo mismo.

Comment: ¿Cual es el comando que usas para compilarlo?. No entiendo lo que quieres hacer, ¿me podrias explicar mejor?

Comment: ¿Intentas hacer?: ´struct s{ int arr[10]; }´    . Main.cpp: ´struct s s;´?

Comment: Por favor, C no es lo mismo que C++. Una respuesta válida para uno de ellos puede no serlo para el otro. Elimina la etiqueta equivocada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te da error de definición múltiple porque, efectivamente, la estás definiendo mas de una vez: no puedes declarar una misma variable mas de una vez **en un mismo espacio de nombres**.

Tus 2 archivos, una vez el preprocesador ha hecho su trabajo, quedarían mas o menos así:

`A.cpp`:

```
int arr[10];
```

`main.cpp`:

```
int arr[10];

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Es evidente que `arr` está **declarada** mas de una vez. Y el enlazador se queja.

La solución es muy simple: avisa al compilador de que existe la variable, sin declararla. Y para ello tenemos la palabra reservada [`extern`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/extern):

`A.h`:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

extern int arr[10];

#endif
```

`A.cpp`:

```
int arr[10];
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "A.h"

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Adicionalmente, desde C++14 en adelante, se soportan las [`inline variables`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline). Con lo cual también podríamos hacer:

`a.h`:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

inline int arr[10];

#endif
```

Al usar `inline`, avisamos al enlazador de que esa variable puede estar declarada mas de una vez ... y que es responsabilidad del propio enlazador eliminar los duplicados y quedarse solo con 1.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda,ya entiendo porque se producía el error y ya lo he solucionado. Muchas gracias.